# Verses 74:38-39 and 56 surah

Tags: quran, tafseer

> And you become [of] three kinds: then the companions of the RIGHT–
> what are the companions of the right? And the companions of the LEFT –
> what are companions of the LEFT? And the forerunners, the forerunners.
> ([56] Al-Waqi'ah : 7-10)

Surah 56 speaks of 3 groups of people: the RIGHT side, the LEFT side, and the forerunners. This surah says that the forerunners and the people of the RIGHT side will be in Paradise, and the people of the LEFT side will be in Hell. But verses 74:38-39 say that everyone will be at a loss **except the people on the RIGHT side**.

> Every soul, for what it has earned, will be retained, except the
> companions of the RIGHT,. ([74] Al-Muddaththir : 38-39)

Only the people of the RIGHT side are mentioned in verses 74:38-39. That is, if you read it literally, verses 74:38-39 contradict surah 56 and send the forerunners to Hell. How to explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Allah don't want any people in LEFT side, as he is most gracious. So he is just giving advice to make them into RIGHT side.
To make it more clear, you can see ثلت and كثير used for these good people(RIGHT and مقربين ones) but no count is specified for LEFT people, only lot of advices to make them into RIGHT

To answer your question, forerunners may be subset of people on RIGHT side, that is why only Right side people is in the verse you mentioned.

Comment: My question is, why are the forerunners omitted in the 74th surah in verses 38-39? Why are only the people on the right side mentioned in this exception, and not the forerunners?

Comment: May be forerunners is subset of People on the RIGHT. Allah knows best.